# Sass Invalid CSS expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "%;"

Tags: sass

I have inherited a site from a development team long gone that used scss to compile the style sheet.  Unfortunately the documentation on how to set up the development environment is non-existant and whilst I have everything else going on the site, the scss / sass compiling process is taking it's toll on my sanity.  I have the following code and various iterations of this pattern throughout the codebase:

```
    @include breakpoint($bp-medium) {
        background-color: transparent;
        width: (100 / 3) + %;
    }
```

The "+ %" at the end of the width statement is being complained about by the compiler.  If I remove it from the formula it compiles fine, but I'm trying to understand what the original intent here was.  Can someone give me some explanation of (what I expect is) old syntax from a few years ago and what the current sass/scss compiler would expect to see to achieve the same result?

I've installed Ruby Sass v3.7.4, and I have deployed bourbon (and fixed up the imports) and neat (and also fixed up the import statements).  I suspect I'm going to end up bashing my head some more on the screen... but any pointers here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(100 / 3) + %
```

is meant to represent the third of 100 in `percentage`.

You can do something like this:

```
$width: percentage(100 / 3);
```

and then use `$width`.